# Routh-Hurwitz Criterion

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am studying a dynamical system with 4 equations. When I evaluate the Jacobian Matrix in a critical point and I see that the trace is zero, how can I use the Routh-Hurwitz Criterion to obtain some conclusion about the stability of the critical point? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues (counted by algebraic multiplicity).  If the trace is $0$, at least one eigenvalue must have nonnegative real part.  If some eigenvalue has positive real part, the critical point is unstable.  However, it is possible that all eigenvalues have real part $0$, e.g. the matrix could be 
$$\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$$
in which case the linearized system is stable but not asymptotically stable, but the nonlinear system could be either stable or unstable, depending on the nonlinear terms.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about continuous system, the trace being 0 just means that the flow is volume preserving. E.g. trace of any fixed point in a Hamiltonian systems is 0, but that fixed point could be a Saddle type (unstable) or center type (marginally stable, 0 real part) point, or a combination of 2 (in higher dimensions, e.g. a Saddle X center in 4 dimensions), and so-on.